# The faq says nothing about accepting answers and accept rate?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, accept-rate, faq-update-request

I vaguely remember that this used to be part of the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq). However it isn't (anymore). Occasionally people remind askers about accepting answers, especially in the light of poor accept rates. Being able to point them to the FAQ would help.

Few people starting out are able to find the deeply hidden ["Accepting answers what's it all about"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Considering this is one of the cornerstones of the SO principles, either a link to that post or a one-liner in the FAQ would benefit the community.

Comment: I would move the part talking about accepting to its own section below the "How do I ask questions here?" for example new section called "How do I accept answers here?" this way it would be as visible as possible to newbies.

Answer (score 3):

From the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask):

> When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer.
>
> [image]
>
> This lets other people know that you have received a good answer to your question. Doing this is helpful because it shows other people that you’re getting value from the community. (And if you don’t do this, people will often politely ask you to go back and accept answers for more of your questions!)

It's in the "How do I ask questions here?" section, but you need to expand it to read it. You can easily link to it, though, like this: https://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask.

Comment: You need to expand "How do I ask question here?" section to see that. Plain search for "accept" in the main faq won't give any results.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd `It's in the "How do I ask questions here?" section, but you need to expand it to read it.` - I know ;P

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd: indeed. And apparently I wasn't smart enough to click the expand-link, I then assume others may not be so smart either (wishful thinking, I know). Nor is there a title on the right that says something like "Why should I accept answers?". I still think it's better suited to be shown at once when landing on the FAQ page, considering the importance of the subject.

Comment: @Yannis lol.. my point was that while true, having it hidden by default makes it harder to find. :-)

Comment: @Abel agreed, see my comment on your question.

Comment: @Abel Well _new_ users should expand and read all sections of the FAQ. If they don't, that's a different issue entirely. In any case, why is accepting answers an important subject? It's a bit annoying when newer users don't, but not a bid deal imho.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd All collapsed sections are similarly "hard to find". Newer users are supposed to expand and read them, it's a 5 minute read. And you can easily draw attention to it, by linking to the expanded version.

Comment: @Yannis true, but I still think that accepting answer is major enough to have its own section.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd Disagree, I think it's an extremely minor issue. But not really what this question is about, if you really feel accepting answers deserves more FAQ visibility, you should post a new question for that and see what the community feels about it.

Comment: @Yannis OK, each and his own opinion. :) I have edited the question tags to contain faq-update-request so it should be clear what update is asked, I have suggested my own idea in a comment to the question.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd I don't think a comment and a tag change the question, it still ask if there's a mention to accepting answers in the FAQ. Post a new one, so consensus can be clear.